# Scripts do not run in KDE power management

Tags: scripts, kde, power-management

I am having some trouble with KDE power management at the time. I have installed tlp and use it for power management.  I have written 3 simple scripts to be run when the computer is on AC/Battery/CritBattery.

They replace tlp's config with the necessary settings and restart it to apply.

The problem is that when KDE loads the respective power profile, it seems to ignore the script... I know it is not the script's fault since invoking it manually does what I tell it to do. (Change the governor and limit max frequency)

Any workarounds are welcome.